# htmltab "no table found" workaround?

Tags: r

I am trying to scrape some (a lot) of NCAA mens basketball data off of a website called RealGM. My code lies below:

```
    library(htmltab)
     tables <- list()
     for (i in 0:1548) {
         for (j in 0:16) {
             for (k in 0:4) {
                  a <- i+1
                  b <- 2003+j
                  c <- k+1
                  url <- paste("https://basketball.realgm.com/ncaa/conferences/Big-Ten-Conference/2/Michigan/",a,"/individual-games/",b,"/minutes/Season/desc/",c,sep = "")
                  tables[[paste(i,j,k,sep = "")]] <- htmltab(url,rm_nodata_cols = F,which = 1)
             }
         }
     }
```

I've used similar methods in the past to pull data off of sites like Sports Reference which keep player data in tables.

In this loop, the variable a controls the team, b controls the year, and c controls the page number for the game log set.

My issue here is that some of the referenced URLs contain no tables, i.e. there is no 4th page of game logs for Michigan's 2003 team, but there are 5 pages for their 2018 team.

Unfortunately, htmltab returns an error when there is not table found, and it aborts my loop. Is there a workaround for this so that it will just skip those urls and/or continue through the rest of the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to do this by checking first to see if a table existed, and if not, go to the next iteration of the loop:

```
    library(htmltab)
    tables <- list()
     for (i in 0:1548) {
             for (j in 0:16) {
                     for (k in 0:4) {
                              a <- i+1
                              b <- 2003+j
                              c <- k+1
                              url <- paste("https://basketball.realgm.com/ncaa/conferences/Big-Ten-Conference/2/Michigan/",a,"/individual-games/",b,"/minutes/Season/desc/",c,sep = "")
                      test <- html_nodes(read_html(url),"table")
                      if (length(test) == 0){
                          next
                      }
                           tables[[paste(i,j,k,sep = "")]] <- htmltab(url,rm_nodata_cols = F,which = 1)
                 }
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `tryCatch` and skip the URL's which give an error.

```
library(htmltab)

tables <- list()
for (i in 1:1549) {
   for (j in 2003:2019) {
     for (k in 1:5) {
       url <- paste0("https://basketball.realgm.com/ncaa/conferences/Big-Ten-Conference/2/Michigan/",i,"/individual-games/",j,"/minutes/Season/desc/",k)
       tables[[paste0(i,j,k)]] <- tryCatch({
        htmltab(url,rm_nodata_cols = F,which = 1)
        }, error = function(e) {
        cat("Wrong URL : ", url, " skipping\n")
        })
       }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I had looked into tryCatch, but was having issues with the syntax. Appreciate it!